# Angular Toggle NgOnChanges for Primitive boolean Types from Parent to Child Input

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I have a Parent and Child component.
The Parent component is trying to send a Test Boolean Flag into the child component input.

We are attempting to toggle NgOnChanges in the Child Component, by conducting this is a method.

```
@Input() Testflag: boolean;
public changeTestFlag(){
    this.TestFlag = false;
    this.TestFlag = true;
}
```

However, this seem to trigger NgOnchanges in Child input, in debugging and tracing.  However, it only reads it as false, not true.  How can this be resolved to be called?

We can do `Object.assign({}, this.testClass)`  for classes; how can we trigger for primitive boolean types?

Comment: Can you show us the template code please? Are you using the @Input property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done by `@Input` decorator in Angular, Please read more here https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#input-and-output-properties

#### Parent Component

In your `parent-component.ts` file you will have the `boolean` variable.

```
testFlag: boolean = true;
```

And in your `parent-component.html` you will call the `child-component` and will pass the `boolean` value as `attribute`.

```
<child-component [flag]="testFlag"></child-component>
```

#### Child Component

Now in your `child-component.ts` you will declare the variable coming from the parent component using `@Input` decorator.

```
@Input() flag: boolean; // 'flag' is set in child component as [flag]
```

And in your `child-component.html` you can use this variable

```
<p *ngIf="flag">Show Flag</p>
```

Comment: would you like to share your code. do you want to change the boolean  value from child component?

Comment: gave points and accepted answer, feel free to thumbs up question, thanks